# Organizing by color

Tags: excel, vba

I have run into an issue, I have a script thanks to several members here has allowed me to import directly from a file into a workbook. With that same script I've incorporated the ability to organize by color red on top, and green underneith. I thought I could write the code to make it so that yellow would be in the middle myself, but it doesn't take into concideration it seems the difference between yellow and red, although I thought I did make that difference noticable though the script.

If someone can look at this and tell me where I am going wrong it would be greatly apprecaited.

This is what I get now for an end result, the yellow is on the bottom of the sheet btw after importing.

[image]

The code for some reason isn't reading right, so attached is also a link to the sheet, with the added file to import.

[Zip File](http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/OO.zip)

or the files seperate here...

[Sheet](http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/OO/OOR.xlms)

[CSV](http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/OO/SO2PO.csv)

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update_POT()

Dim wsPOD As Worksheet
Dim wsPOT As Worksheet
Dim wsPOA As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim lastrow As Long, fstcell As Long, i As Long, Er As Long, lstCol As Long, lstRow As Long, strFile As String

Set wsPOD = Sheets("PO Data")
Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")
Set wsPOA = Sheets("PO Archive")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With wsPOD
        .Columns("A:AB").ClearContents
        .Range("Y1").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('PO Tracking'!$D:$D,$C1,'PO Tracking'!$C:$C,$D1,'PO Tracking'!$F:$F,$G1)"
        .Range("Z1").Formula = "=IF($M1,"""",""Different"")"
        .Range("AA1").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($C1),0,1)"
        .Range("AB1").Formula = "=IF($O1,""Full"","""")"
    End With

    strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please selec text file...")

    With wsPOD.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=wsPOD.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
    End With


    With wsPOD
    'first bring columns F:G up to match their line
    For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(5), .Columns(6))

        If cel = vbNullString And cel.Offset(, -2) <> vbNullString Then
            .Range(cel.Offset(1), cel.Offset(1, 1)).Copy cel
            cel.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    'now fil columns A:D to match PO Date and PO#
    For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(5), .Columns(1))

        If cel = vbNullString And cel.Offset(, 5) <> vbNullString Then
            .Range(cel.Offset(-1), cel.Offset(-1, 3)).Copy cel
        End If
    Next
        lastrow = wsPOD.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        fstcell = wsPOD.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        wsPOD.Range("Y1:AB1").Copy wsPOD.Range("M" & fstcell & ":P" & lastrow)
        wsPOD.Range("M:P").Calculate
    End With

        With Intersect(wsPOD.UsedRange, wsPOD.Columns("P"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Full"
        With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("A:P"))
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With Intersect(wsPOD.UsedRange, wsPOD.Columns("N"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Different"
        With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("A:P"))
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    'Final Adjustments before transfering over to PO Tracking.
    With wsPOD
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastrow = wsPOD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A4:A" & lastrow)).Cut .Range("Q3")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("D")).Cut .Range("R1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("C")).Cut .Range("S1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("B")).Cut .Range("T1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("G")).Cut .Range("U1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("F")).Cut .Range("V1")
     End With

    With wsPOD
        wsPOD.Columns("A:P").ClearContents
        lastrow = wsPOD.Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
        wsPOD.Range("Q3:V" & lastrow).Copy wsPOT.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    'Format PO Tracking

    With wsPOT
        .Range("Q1:U1").Copy
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("V1:X1").Copy .Range("H3:J" & lastrow)
        .Range("N2:O2").Copy .Range("N3:O" & lastrow)
        .Range("P1:V1").Copy
        .Range("B3:H" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Range("K3:K" & lastrow).Borders.Weight = xlThin
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("H:J").Calculate

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear

    'Sort PO Tracking

    'Sort Reds
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("J3:J" & lastrow), _
        xlSortOnIcon, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SetIcon Icon:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        IconSets(4).Item(1)

        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "J3:J30" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

    'Sort Yellows
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("I3:I" & lastrow), _
        xlSortOnIcon, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SetIcon Icon:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        IconSets(4).Item(2)

        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "I3:I" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

    'Sort Greens
        .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("I3:I" & lastrow), _
        xlSortOnIcon, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SetIcon Icon:=ActiveWorkbook. _
        IconSets(4).Item(3)

        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "I3:I" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

        With .Sort
            .SetRange wsPOT.Range("B2:K" & lastrow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With


    With wsPOD
        wsPOD.Columns("Q:X").ClearContents
        wsPOD.Cells(1, 25).Value = "=COUNTIFS('PO Tracking'!$D:$D,$C1,'PO Tracking'!$C:$C,$D1,'PO Tracking'!$F:$F,$G1)"
        wsPOD.Cells(1, 27).Value = "=IF(ISBLANK($C1),0,1)"
        wsPOD.Range("Y1:AB1").Copy wsPOD.Range("M5:P5")
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
         .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your COl H formulas in OOR file have Ref# errors so I cant test it...

Comment: Try now, it should work.

Comment: Yes it works but I do not see any Yellow Icons?

Comment: You won't, hence the 2nd file, it will allow you to import, and then you should see between 2 to 3 icons... I've written the script in such a way that it's manditory to keep moving.  Otherwise it won't continue because there is no new data to import.

Comment: Lemme have a look in detail and get back to you...

Comment: Hey Matt, you could probably find a way to use the color of the icons to do your sort, but a much more straightforward way to do it(in my opinion) would be to just use whatever logic you are using to determine the colors to do your sort. I don't know if that is in another column, or if it's in your vba script(I didn't look at your files) -but colors in the end are just arbitrary - they don't really tell you anything just by themselves without some reference to subjective culture. Gradations of grey could be used in math but for red,blue,yellow- They mean different things in different cultures.

Comment: I needed two columns, the red are late, yellow are due today, and green are due in a weeks time or more. Red is in a column by itself, yellow and green share their own column... this was a requirement honestly.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout, thanks :) I figured putting the `IconSets(4).Item(2)` would then organize the yellows, but guess not.

Comment: Is this what you are trying? http://wikisend.com/download/583452/Untitled.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the line

```
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "I3:I" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
```

in

```
    'Sort Yellows
    .Sort.SortFields.Add(.Range("I3:I" & lastrow), _
    xlSortOnIcon, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SetIcon Icon:=ActiveWorkbook. _
    IconSets(4).Item(2)

    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "I3:I" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
```

You cannot have have the same duplicate sort conditions for both Yellow and Green in the same column. Remove that line and try again.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. when I duplicated it, I figured it would only take the color in question and organize it, instead of the way it acted.  So much for second guessing Excel VBA...